# Java Regex replace a line matching a specific text

Tags: java, regex

I've such string:

```
String s = "foo\nbar\nfoo\nbar\nfoo\nbar";
```

Which looks like this if printed to console:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

I want to remove each line which equals "bar". I've tried

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?s)bar", ""));

foo

foo

foo
```

and

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?s)bar\n", ""));

foo
foo
foo
bar
```

What should i append to my regex to get

```
foo
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the quantifier `?` after `\n`. It means none or once.

```
(?s)bar\n?
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution gives me an empty line at the end, but that is not a problem, solved it by adding trim `s.replaceAll("(?s)bar\n?", "").trim()`

Comment: Removing all `\nbar` rather than `bar\n` makes more sense. In that case you don't need to remove trailing `\n`